# Which web framework is being used in doit.im?

Tags: web, frameworks

I'm curious to know what web framework is being used in these to do list websites:

http://www.doit.im and
http://www.nirvanahq.com

(I'm referring to the to do list functionality available *after* you login to the site - not the webpages you see when browsing the site...)

The user interface elements are very similar suggesting the same web framework.

I know very little about web frameworks, however for someone with experience in this domain, the answer may be simple.

:)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Doit.im (which I use) appears to use angular. Open the console and type angular to see the global variable; usually the main app is registered and can be retrieved by running angular.module ('[insert name]'). With Nirvana, I just see a bunch of jQuery and variables stored in NIRV.